# Вызов метода в наследнике, перекрытого с помощью new + UpCast

Tags: c#, наследование

Имею следующие классы:

```
class A
{
    virtual public void OutPut()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class A");
    }
 }

class B : A
{
     new public void OutPut()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class B");
    }
}
```

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что класс B не переопределяет метод вывода, а скрывает определение метода из класса А с помощью оператора new.
Далее в вызывающей части произвожу UpCast, вызываю метод вывода, в дополнение отдельной командой определяю тип во время выполнения с помощью GetType():

```
static void Main()
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.OutPut();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Вывод:

```
Class A
SecondTest.B
```

Вопрос: как правильно объяснить происходящее? Почему выводится версия метода из класса A, но в тоже время, динамическая идентификация типа во время выполнения говорит, что это класс  B?

Comment: `new` не переопределяет метод, а заменяет. Для переопределения замените `new` на `override`.

Comment: @aepot я не уточняю, что нужно сделать для переопределения. Я хочу узнать, почему происходит именно то, что происходит. Как это правильно объяснить. В переменной класса A на самом деле лежит объект класса B, но вызывается версия метода из класса A.

Comment: Roslyn просто берет метод от типа A - `A.OutPut`, потому что он не переопределен. В данном случае все равно, какой реальный тип у объекта в дереве наследников. Если метод не переопределен - вызывается его непереопределенная версия. Всё просто.

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160095/8269227) этот вопрос разбирается

Comment: [Versioning with the Override and New Keywords](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/versioning-with-the-override-and-new-keywords), [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)

Comment: Просто поделюсь ссылкой, опытным разработчикам на заметку: есть вот [такой фокус](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64295242/12888024) в C#8.0 с Default Interface Methods.